# Creating a real unit test in Karma for Angular code

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular-2+, integration-testing, jasmine

This is a piece of test code made for the Angular application.

The router object is a mock provided by the RouterTestingModule dependency. I wonder if such a test **can be considered a unit test** (because it actually tests only one element and the fact that it calls some method - without checking its result), **or should it be called an integration test** (due to the fact that it still call external dependence)?

```js
it('should trigger the navigation to `/home`', async(() => {
  const link = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.home-link');

  link.click();

  expect(router.navigateByUrl).toHaveBeenCalled();
}))
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Did you create this code or do you maintain it?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't asking for code review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

> - `router` object is a mock, and
> - the fact that it calls some method - without checking its result

You have a *unit test*, more specifically a [whitebox test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-box_testing), as opposed to a *blackbox test* that tests the output of some method.

For it to become an *integration test*, you would have use a router instead of a mock.